# OpenGL glTexCoordPointer seemingly not applying texture

Tags: opengl, textures, vbo, vertex-buffer

I have the code:

```
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture ); 

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);  
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, coordsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( texcoords ), texcoords , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);  
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(float) / 3);
```

And I'm puzzled as to why the quads are being drawn perfectly well but the texture isn't being mapped at all.

Unrolling sections into calls to `glTexCoord2f` and `glVertex3f` works perfectly well so I can only assume I'm doing something wrong with my texture bindings.

texcoords is being initialised with:

```
GLfloat texcoords[] = {   1.0, 0.0
                        , 1.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0
                        , 1.0, 0.0
                        , 1.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0
                         ,1.0, 0.0
                         ,1.0, 1.0
                         ,1.0, 1.0
                         ,1.0, 0.0
                        , 1.0, 1.0
                        , 1.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 0.0, 1.0
                        , 1.0, 0.0
                        , 1.0, 0.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0
                        , 0.0, 0.0 }
```

And left unchanged for now, it's the same number of pairs as my vertex array has vertex triplets.

I'm getting GL_NO_ERROR and the faces are all coloured as the default value set with the initial call to `glColor3f(0.9f, 0.1f, 1.0f);`

Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Tried glGetError? What are you seeing instead of a texture? Can you show the texcoords data and initialization?

Comment: Ok, the question is updated, no error and the faces are all the colour defined by the most recent call to `glColor3f`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can bind 2 seperated VBOs as you have ... Shouldn't you just interleave the vertices and texture coords into 1 VBO and draw that as a one'r?

Comment: @Goz - It's perfectly acceptable to assign pointers to separate VBOs as he is doing there.

Comment: Perhaps missing [`glClientActiveTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClientActiveTexture.xml), if not using texture 0? Otherwise that looks fine to me.

Comment: Damn it, sorry to waste your time everyone, I seemingly actually loading a texture helps...sorry.